# Identifying geolocation of user by other than HTML5 Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, geolocation

I am writing an web application in Jsp that requires to identify the geolocation of the user. I have tried the code of w3schools using HTML5 geolocation api. But it is not executing on Tomcat. I have posted that problem here but got no solution. So I think it cannot be done.

So now I am looking for alternative ways to do the same. I am asking is there any other way by which I can identify the current location of the user? Actually I am new to web technologies. So if anyone give any idea regarding this I will be really grateful. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Is it possible to use **whois** to identify the location of an user?

Comment: It can be done, and apart from IP-based geolocation which is much more fuzzy, HTML 5 geolocation is the only way. I would try again.

Comment: @Joy keep in mind that geolocating may not work all the time. It works upon browser support and that user allows the website to get the location.

Comment: Sir,could you please give any clue regarding that?

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Sir what are the ways so that I can track the geolocation of user always?

Comment: I think IP geolocating may be the best option because it works always and can be relied on. But it can be faked with changing IPs. You can try to implement both of the ways and compare their results. and get a final deduction of the user's location

Comment: About the whois, Yes it's possible to do whois (generally IP-Lookup) to identify the location

Comment: @MiroMarkarian IP geolocating may be the best option, but it is not running on my machine. So I am looking for alternative ways that I have not yet found.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Geo location in HTML5 Application use corodva JS 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
      'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
      'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
      'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
      'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
      'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
      'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
      'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object

function onError(error) {
alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: it is not executing on my machine.I don't know why. Probably for the same reason the code in W3schools using HTML5 geolocation api did not run.